# How to use the Xcode ios-simulator for smaller devices than the iphone 4s?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, render, xcode7

In Xcode(7.1):

How can I simulate for smaller devices than the iphone4s? So I can see how the image assets @1x get rendered?

Comment: There are no devices smaller than the iPhone 4s.

Comment: If you want to test 1x images, use a non-retina iPad such as the IPad 2.

Comment: ok yea, I used the wrong words. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test @1x media resolution, your only option, for now, is with iPad 2 simulator, because this is the last current supported device with non-retina screen.
I suppose this device shall not be supported with iOS10, so there will be no need for @1x media. I guess we won't see it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Whether @1x images are used has nothing to do with the *size* of the device. It has to do with the *resolution* of this device's *screen*.

Comment: ok yea, I was using the wrong words. but meant resolution indeed. thanks